# Hightlight Current Link in Navigation not working in Edge only

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have set up a simple menu which highlights the current page a user is on by displaying with a crimson red background. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

However, when I view in **Edge**, it only partly works. It is highlighting the current page but setting the background colour to white and not crimson red.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, and why **Edge** is choosing a white background for the active/current link instead of the crimson red?  The code is displayed below.

Thanks,

Andy ;-)

The Navigation Menu (HTML/PHP)

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li class="<?php if ( $page == "index" ) { echo "current"; } ?>"><a href="index.php" title="Home Page of Site">Home</a></li>
<li class="<?php if ( $page == "page2" ) { echo "current"; } ?>"><a href="page2.php" title="page2 of site">Page2</a></li>
<li class="<?php if ( $page == "page3" ) { echo "current"; } ?>"><a href="page3.php" title="page3 of site">Page3</a></li>
<li class="<?php if ( $page == "page4" ) { echo "current"; } ?>"><a href="page4.php" title="Page4 of site">Page4</a></li>
</ul>      
</nav>
```

The Navigation Menu (CSS)

```
.mainHeader nav{
    background-color: #444;
    font-size: 1.143em;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;}

.mainHeader nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;}

.mainHeader nav ul li{
    float: left;
    display: inline;}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited{
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 23px;
    height: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active, .mainHeader nav  ul li.current a:link, .mainHeader nav ul li.current a:visited{
    background-color:#DC143C;  /* Crimson Red Background for Current Link */
    color:#fff;  /* White font colour for Current Link *
} 

.mainHeader nav li a{
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;}
```

Comment: Edge is not IE and I wouldn't call it ME either cause some may read it as Microsoft ME, a former Microsoft operating system. Just call it Edge and we know what you mean.

Comment: Thanks Rob, all changed.  Another thing I just noticed, when I deleted Edge History, and reload a page on the site, the active link colour, crimson red, displays correctly. However, when I click any other link on the main nav thereafter it starts displaying with a white background again.

Comment: Ah, figured it out.

I broke **current a:link** and **current a:visited** into two separate css statements.

It now works across all three browsers: Chrome, Firefox & Edge.

If anyone knows why you have to separate them, please let me know, Andy :-)